# Grid that shows payments and refunds at the same time

Tags: grid, payment, billing

I have a grid where I need to show payments made by user and also refunds that could be issued to that user. How can I format the grid in order to make easy to differentiate payments and refunds, without making the user feel that payments are a bad thing (e.g. not to use red font color for payment)?

The columns of the grid are:

- Order
- Amount
- Date

Comment: Red doesn't always equate to bad. It's the way you present it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just follow what PayPal do, it's clearly enough differentiated with using red and green (obviously there's colour blind issues with these colours) and +/- but it leaves the prices in black:

[image]